# C question on free()

Tags: c, malloc, free

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()

{

   int *p = (int *)malloc((100*sizeof(int)));

   p++;

   free(p);

/* do something */

return 0;

}
```

Questions:

1. Will the memory starting from the location p+1 be free(say if malloc returned 0x1000, the memory freed will be from 0x1004,assuming a 4 byte integer)?
2. Are there anypitfalls of this code apart from the fact that the 4 bytes from 0x1000(if malloc returned 0x1000) are not useable (unless you do a p-- and use the address)

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please read the editing help to see how to format code properly.

Comment: For some hints not directly concerned with your question, but with your code: (1) in C, don't cast the return from `malloc` this may hide the bug of not including "stdlib.h", such as in your example. Your code may then fail when you go from a 32 bit machine to 64 bit. (2) don't "reinvent" a signature for `main`. In C `int main()` and `int main(void)` are not the same.

Answer (score 12):

That's undefined behavior - you must pass exactly the same pointer to `free()` as you obtained from `malloc()`. With your code anything can happen - likely heap will be corrupted.

Think of it this way. `free()` has only one parameter, so it must deduce what to mark free from exactly that one parameter. There's no way to "free less memory" - either it will free all (deduction required for that will be very time-consuming btw), or something bad happens - the latter is more likely. You shouldn't assume anything, just don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

The free() call will fail, because p is no longer the address of a block allocated with malloc().

Comment: Not necessarily it will fail. It might covertly corrupt heap and you won't notice until much later.

Comment: it is undefined behaviour as 'sharptooth' suggested above. free() will not fail.

Comment: Yes, it may not return an error value, but silently screw things up. It's undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This code just won't work - you can only free pointers that were allocated by malloc or similar function, you can't free part of the allocated memory range.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried this code over gcc and it stopped with:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0829600c ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6b591)[0x7be591]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x6cde8)[0x7bfde8]
/lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x7c2ecd]
```

So as per your first answer you can't free the next memory location.
and for the second question:
and the four bytes won't be usable unless you do p-- and this code will work fine unless you change the contents of next memory location and you can use the allocated memory location by doing p--

Comment: "This particular C++ implementation" doesn't necessarily mean "this is the correct answer." It's the correct answer for that implementation, but not for the language, "C++".

Answer (score 0):

in standardese this behavior is "undefined", but actually, nothing will get freed.
the reason is that what malloc does it keep a list of the chunks it had allocated, each chunk is identified by its *starting* address. 
p+1 is not on that list, so free will find a chunk to free, and will do nothing.